Retrieving Collaborator Repositories: Challenges with Service Account PATs
Use Case:
A GitHub service account's PAT is required to fetch complete repository details, including commit information, in two scenarios:

Organization Membership: The service account is a member of an organization containing the target private repository.
Repository Collaboration: The service account is a collaborator on an organization's private repository with read/write access.

Problem:
I'm encountering difficulties retrieving a list of repositories where my GitHub service account is a collaborator using its Personal Access Token (PAT). Despite having the necessary permissions, I'm unable to retrieve the desired information using the GET /user/repos endpoint with the affiliation=collaborator parameter.
I've explored different approaches, including creating PATs with various ownership models:

Service Account Owned PAT: Faces limitations in accessing organization-level data.
Organization Owned PAT: Provides broader access but requires additional management.

I'm seeking guidance on overcoming these challenges, identifying the optimal PAT configuration, and effectively retrieving collaborator repositories using a service account.
Specific Issues:

Inconsistent results when using different PAT ownership models.
Difficulty in determining the exact permissions required for successful retrieval.
Limitations of the GET /user/repos endpoint in this context.
Tried the required scopes(content scope, repo scope) in PAT creation but ending up with 404(Not Found) error
Not able to fetch the repos and it's details of which the GitHub service is collaborator of.

I've attempted the following approaches:

Creating a PAT with different ownership models: Tried creating PATs owned by the service account and the organization to see if ownership affects access to collaborator repositories.

Experimenting with different scopes: Tested various combinations of scopes, including repo and admin:org, to determine the necessary permissions.

Utilizing the GET /user/repos, /repos/{owner}/{repo}/collaborators, repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits endpoint: Employed this endpoint repositories, collaborators and commits.

Error handling: Implemented basic error handling to identify potential API rate limits or other issues.

Sample API code tried : I am working on python so tried the below also tried oon
url = f'https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits'
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'token {token}',
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'
    }

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)



I expected to successfully retrieve a list of repositories where the service account is a collaborator, along with their details, using the appropriate PAT configuration and API endpoint. However, I consistently encountered issues like 404 errors and incomplete data retrieval.
Additional Notes:

I've verified that the service account has the necessary permissions within the organization.
I've considered potential API rate limits and implemented basic retry mechanisms.

Expected Output:

A list of repositories where the service account is a collaborator or could be a member of that organization with required read permissions of private repos, including details like name, owner, URL, and commit information.

